# Ionic: How to Open a view on click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created following main screen. On clicking each link it has to open corresponding view.

[image]

So far I have written:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Checkout</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="row blue-bg">
          <div class="col col-50 white">
            <ul class="list-inline">
              <li><a href="#">Catalog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Transaction</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-40 white">Logo</div>
          <div class="col col-10 .col-offset-25 white">Right</div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
    .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        if (window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
      });
    })
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
    .controller('PaymentListCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.productItems = [
            {
                name: 'Product 1',
                price: '$50.00'
            },
            {
                name: 'Product 2',
                price: '$45.00'
            }
        ]
    })
```

Please note I am new in both Ionic and Angular. If you can provide a simple to use method then would be greatful

Comment: So you want to use [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)?

Comment: @Goldenowner Ideally it seems so. Further explaination please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to define state and redirect your view

```
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Checkout</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="row blue-bg">
          <div class="col col-50 white">
            <ul class="list-inline">
              <li><a href="#">Catalog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Transaction</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-40 white">Logo</div>
          <div class="col col-10 .col-offset-25 white">Right</div>
        </div>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

Define your view in another page
view1.html

```
 <ion-view view-title="Admin">
    <ion-content class="padding text-center">
      //define your content here
    </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

in app.js define state like this

```
.state('main', {
            url: '/index',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: '{{yourpath}}/index.html'
        })
        .state('main.view', {
            url: '/view',
            templateUrl: '{{yourpath}}/admin.html',


        })
```

may be this can help you

Comment: Arsalan, where are you setting `yourpath` variable? or.. what it should be?

Comment: you are using ionic framework then it will be like templates/foldername/filename.html

Answer (score 1):

I just made a simple and clear [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wpLS0bapa5vpOI5Wxepw?p=preview).

Index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <!-- Make a fancy menu here -->
  <a href="#/">Welcome</a>
  <a href="#/goodbye">Exit</a>

  <!-- The templates will be inserted here -->
  <ng-view></ng-view>

</body
```

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'welcome.tmpl.html',
      controller: 'welcomeCtrl'
    }).
    when('/goodbye', {
      templateUrl: 'goodbye.tmpl.html',
      controller: 'goodbyeCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  //Code goes here
});

app.controller('welcomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.welcome = "Welcome to the 'Welcome' page";
});

app.controller('goodbyeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.goodbye = "Goodbye? I guess?";
});
```

And ofcourse we need the template to insert and those are just 2 simple `.html` files which not containt `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>`.

Hope you got enough information, if not jus let me know.

Comment: Given the fact he uses ionic, I think it would be best to use ionic's own routing: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: says that it failed to load `ngRoute`. How to include ngRoute in Ionic app?

Comment: @devqon If you read my comment on the question he agreed with using `ngRoute`, and that is an AngularJS method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some help from this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paritosh/et1vz1sh/16/)

Actually copied from this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasperkuperus/et1vz1sh/)

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
////.....
  $scope.triggerViewUpdate = function() {
     // JSFiddle didn't seem to like ng-template script tags...
     $ionicModal.fromTemplate('<ion-modal-view>...Content...</ion-modal-view>').show();
  };
})
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button button-positive button-block button-outline" ng-click="triggerViewUpdate()">Trigger View update</button>
```

Comment: But to call it on click?